# Tool take UI screenshots of different browsers and compare with a define base line

Tags: internet-explorer, ui-automation, browser-automation, multiple-browsers

I'm looking for a tool that can provide me to identify UI changes on each regression round on multiple browsers. Please recommend the tools or a method to get the following.

- Take the screenshots of a website on IE and Safari (and other main browsers).
- When the tests are execute multiple times, should be able to identify if there are any UI changes automatically without user involvement
- If that identified UI change is an expected update to the website, user can manually set that screenshot as the base line and use it to compare with the upcoming screenshots

My basic requirement is to automatically detect the UI changes and get informed about those on main browsers including IE and Safari.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is no tool available that can identify the UI changes on the web page for cross-browser.

I suggest you check the Selenium web driver. It can work with all major browsers and it can be used to automate the web browser. it is also available for cross-browser support.

There is no ready-made code available for your specific requirements but you can try to develop the code to fulfill your specific tasks.

Then after if you meet with an issue then you can create a thread here. We can try to check it and try to provide suggestions for it.

Reference:

[Selenium WebDriver](https://selenium.dev/projects/)